# Differences between hxtt and ucanaccess

Tags: jdbc, ucanaccess, hxtt

I know both work. I know ucanaccess is open source. I just wonder if there are any benefits in still using hxtt.

I have some corruption issues with hxtt, so I'm trying to understand if it's a good approach to completely switch over to ucanaccess.

So far the differences I have seen is that ucanaccess is more strict about data inserted into the database, but there might be more differences I should be aware of.

Comment: I don't know how  hxtt works, but which are the  UCanAccess restrictions  you're speaking about? My main aim is to avoid each restriction in inserting data, so may you refer to any specific issue you're facing with?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I've actually decided to migrate to ucanaccess. HXTT will automatically truncate strings that don't fit in a field, and it also hides some errors in order for the process to continue. But it can also corrupt the database so I can't continue to use it.